# Handling RDDs to an specific worker in Apache Spark

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, executor

Do you know if it is possible to set which RDD goes to which executor?

Something similar to a parallel programming in which can be defined which thread or process handles which piece of data.

I have looked for that and it seems it is not possible, so I would like to confirm, because, maybe It is just that I have not found the information yet.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No it is not possible with Spark.